# Non-Sanforized Gaposis?

Tags: meaning

What does that mean? What is non-sanfordized gaposis? It sounds like an illness of some kind but I could not find it.  The context is:

> In Bygone days, before you were demoralized by Static Cling, it was
>   halitosis, or B.O. or unsightly snaps or non-Sanforized Gaposis

—[Anton Szandor LaVey, *The Devil's Notebook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ME5jCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA14&ots=r5bfhF4pTl&dq=%22In%20Bygone%20days%2C%20before%20you%20were%20demoralized%20by%20Static%20Cling%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22In%20Bygone%20days,%20before%20you%20were%20demoralized%20by%20Static%20Cling%22&f=false)

Comment: You can find "gaposis" listed in at least some dictionaries, see here: http://www.dictionary.com/wordoftheday/2016/09/02/gaposis and here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gaposis

Comment: It's nothing. It's just two words out together in a rather odd way. Both words can be found by Googling them, but the combination means nothing in particular, just a case of gaposis (a series of gaps, such as between buttons on clothes) that has not been sanfor(d)ised (treated to reduce shrinking in the wash). Without knowing the context, there's no way for anyone to tell you what that is supposed to be a reference to.

Comment: Excuse me, you are right. the sentence reads: " In Bygone days, before you were demoralized by Static Cling, it was halitosis, or B.O. or unsightly snaps or non-Sanforized Gaposis.

Comment: The sentence is a litany about the pressures of advertising--all the things we're persuaded to worry about.

Comment: The list the term appears in is of 'problems' related to personal appearance/hygiene which have essentially been invented, or exaggerated, by the advertising industry in order to promote products by making us feel insecure. This one sounds odd because the writer has included the name of the product/process which 'solves' the problem. 'Sanforized cotton' won't shrink, so a blouse won't develop gaposis after laundering.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a combination of terms used in clothing manufacture.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanforization):

> Sanforization is a process of treatment used for cotton fabrics mainly and most textiles made from natural or chemical fibres, patented by Sanford Lockwood Cluett (1874–1968) in 1930. It is a method of stretching, shrinking and fixing the woven cloth in both length and width before cutting and producing, to reduce the shrinkage which would otherwise occur after washing.

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/gaposis):

> gaposis, noun, *informal*
>
> a gap between closed fastenings on a garment

Putting them together, **non-sanforized gaposis** would appear to be the gaping between buttons (or snaps) created when the clothing which was not sanforized (pre-treated to prevent shrinkage) shrinks.

Comment: It seems to be essentially two general-reference questions.